# Binding data to checkbox in custom activity designer

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I have a custom activity, with a boolean property. My problem is i have no clue how to bind the checkbox in the designer.

Thank's

Comment: There are tutorials available.  Go read one.  Try something.  Come back when you're stuck.

Comment: This might help you, since we do not knwo where you are stuck. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2011/04/06/wf4-showing-an-inargument-lt-bool-gt-as-a-checkbox-in-the-workflow-designer-property-grid.aspx